# Grant Keyvault access policy to service principal using terraform

Tags: terraform-provider-azure

I want to grant an existing service principal policies of Azure Keyvault using terraform.

Also, a terraform script that creates and grants the SP access on a keyvault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AKV now supports RBAC, so here you go, an example with the SP which executes Terraform and the Role Key Vault Secrets Officer (principal_id can be replaced with your designated SP) :

```
data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "akv_sp" {
  scope                = azurerm_key_vault.akv.id
  role_definition_name = "Key Vault Secrets Officer"
  principal_id         = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id
}
```

Comment: this is the setting needed for Terraform Enterprise's Service Principal